# Is a VPN and Virtual Machine secure enough for running programs that might include malware

Tags: network, malware, vpn, virtualization

I am trying to start a business online but don't want viruses from any sketchy software that I will be downloading. I will be using a VM and a VPN but was wondering if I needed any other software so my computer, network etc will not be affected. I understand not to have shared files on and all that but still don't know for sure because some people say some malware can get through Virtual Machines.

Comment: can you be more specific which operating system will you be using ? Perhaps you can try linux based os for more security and read some articles how to make the linux enviroment more secure. If you are planning to store sensitive infrormation you should consider an encryption of this information so in case anyhow you get infected it will be hard to obtain this sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Running Malware in a safe environment is called Sandboxing. A virtual machine and VPN Combo is an excellent choice for a Sandbox environment.

The risk comes down to if the attacker can break out of the virtual environment and that comes down to what Virtualization software you are using. Other than that as long as you are careful not to enter sensitive information and you disable the shared clipboard then the risk is very minimal. But remember like everything in the Cyber Security world you are just minimizing risk, there is always a small chance that something can go wrong with any solution.